# Out of Memory on Bitmap Android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I want to make implement this in android
[image]
For this, I have to load images from asset folder and I am making two `HorizontalScrollView` in xml file and load dynamically `ImageView` in it. For loading ImageView I am using this code

```
LinearLayout myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

try {
    String galleryDirectoryName = "gallery";
    String[] listImages = getAssets().list(galleryDirectoryName);
    for (String imageName : listImages) {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(galleryDirectoryName + "/" + imageName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));

        //   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myGallery1=  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        myGallery1.setMargins(20, 0,  10, 0);

        //its is also working
        // imageView.setLayoutParams(myGallery1);       

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //   diplayImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });

        Log.e("GalleryWithHorizontalScrollView", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

**//Repeating Above code to load imageView in second horizontalScrollView**

```
LinearLayout myGallery2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery2);

try {
    String galleryDirectoryName1 = "gallery2";
    String[] listImages2 = getAssets().list(galleryDirectoryName1);
    for (String imageName : listImages2) {
        InputStream is1 = getAssets().open(galleryDirectoryName1 + "/" + imageName);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));

        //  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myGallery21=  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        myGallery21.setMargins(20, 40,  10, 0);

        //its is also working

        myGallery.addView(imageView,myGallery1);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    myGallery2.addView(imageView,myGallery21);
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("GalleryWithHorizontalScrollView", e.getMessage(), e);
}
}
```

If I make one horizontalScrollView and load imageviews in it then it works fine but for second horizontalScrollView it gives me error at line 76

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);
```

and my Log cat is this

```
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:643)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at com.example.gallery.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
05-14 11:13:26.000: E/AndroidRuntime(8350):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how much is the size of each image? you need to recycle bitmaps when not in use

Comment: hmm, you can also [check out this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: there are total 12 images in them 4 are 1024x780 while rest are 200x200 size.... where to call bitmap.recycle()....i am just loading images 2 times in actitvity alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html),

and most important thing you should consider is to optimize your bitmap for your thumbnail.
Try this :

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromInput(Context context,
        InputStream input, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
}
```

Here reqWidth is width of thumbnail and same for reqHeight.

and For listView try to implement a cache for your bitmaps and try to get them by using a unique key may be file name (because you should not save same images multiple times)

Comment: hmm, you can also [check out this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: You can also add 

options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;

Answer (score 0):

Simple, dont load to much Images ...

Use some caching like an LRUCache with an fixed size. If Image is missing you have to load them first. Should increase performance and fix your OOME

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Comment: google play store has lot of images. you can scroll down the list. "Simple, dont load to much Images" is not the answer. lazy loading or UIL should help in this case

Comment: Their manage the memory aswel, so their not load all once. Thats where LRU comes to play

Answer (score 0):

You need to access images using *BitmapFactory.Options*

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize =8;
```

then

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1,null,options);
```

So that only required size bitmap is loaded into memory

For more see [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)